# Not able to install testlink on linux for the very first time

Tags: linux, testlink

I am trying to install `testlink 1.9.8` on `Linux 6.2` via **automatic scripts** provided by `testlink`
I have default `linux apache 2.2` running with `mysql 5.3`.

When i am proceeding the steps in testlink installation then It is trying to upgrade the testlink but i never installed testlink on that machine.

any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.codylab.com/install-testlink-on-centos/ This would surely help you and proceed with new installation on webpage.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: Hi Alok, Your refrence blog helped me but i got a problem with login into testlink after installing test link

Comment: what is the problem you face while login

Comment: I am not getting any error. When i put username and password there then clicking login is refreshing the browser.

Comment: Default username and password of testlink is admin/admin what are you trying

Comment: Can you help me for debugging this. I am stuck at this point.

Comment: Also i delete admin user using SQL command. But when creating new user that is also not able to login

Comment: At the time of installation did you followed the steps

Comment: when i start with fresh installation then why test link redirect to Upgrade of Testlink. whereas i dont have testlink on my system